# Error while building Ant in liferay portlet

Tags: tomcat, ant, liferay, liferay-6

I'm getting the following error when I tried to build Ant with liferay portlets.

```
    Buildfile: C:\Temp\LifeRay\liferay-plugins-sdk-6.2-ce-ga4-20150416163831865\liferay-plugins-sdk-6.2\portlets\Sample-portlet\build.xml
deploy:

BUILD FAILED
C:\Temp\LifeRay\liferay-plugins-sdk-6.2-ce-ga4-20150416163831865\liferay-plugins-sdk-6.2\build-common.xml:2880: The following error occurred while executing this line:
: The following error occurred while executing this line:
C:\Temp\LifeRay\liferay-plugins-sdk-6.2-ce-ga4-20150416163831865\liferay-plugins-sdk-6.2\build-common.xml:1363: The following error occurred while executing this line:
: The following error occurred while executing this line:
C:\Temp\LifeRay\liferay-plugins-sdk-6.2-ce-ga4-20150416163831865\liferay-plugins-sdk-6.2\build-common.xml:2596: The following error occurred while executing this line:
: The following error occurred while executing this line:
C:\Temp\LifeRay\liferay-plugins-sdk-6.2-ce-ga4-20150416163831865\liferay-plugins-sdk-6.2\build-common.xml:591: The following error occurred while executing this line:
C:\Temp\LifeRay\liferay-plugins-sdk-6.2-ce-ga4-20150416163831865\liferay-plugins-sdk-6.2\build-common.xml:927: C:\Temp\LifeRay\liferay-plugins-sdk-6.2-ce-ga4-20150416163831865\bundles\tomcat-7.0.42\webapps\ROOT\WEB-INF\lib does not exist.
```

Total time: 3 seconds

Need some help...! thanks in advance.

Comment: Did you read the error message? Does the folder mentioned in it (`C:\Temp\LifeRay\liferay-plugins-sdk-6.2-ce-ga4-20150416163831865\bundles\tomcat-7.0.42\webapps\ROOT\WEB-INF\lib`) exist or not? What did you try yet?

Comment: yes i got the error message as mentioned..

Answer (score 4):

This usually happens when you don't specify your Tomcat bundle location and it's not in the default location.

Create a file named `$PLUGINS_SDK/build.${user.name}.properties` where `${user.name}` is the name of the user in your system. In that file you can overwrite the values of any of the properties in the `$PLUGINS_SDK/build.properties` file. Some common properties that are overridden (with example values) are:

```
app.server.dir=/my-dir/appservers/liferay-portal-tomcat-jdk5-trunk
auto.deploy.dir=${user.home}/liferay/deploy
app.server.lib.portal.dir=/my-dir/liferay/trunk/portal-web/docroot/WEB-INF/lib
app.server.portal.dir=/my-dir/liferay/trunk/portal-web/docroot
javac.compiler=modern
```

For more info: [Liferay wiki - Plugins SDK Preparation](http://www.liferay.com/community/wiki/-/wiki/Main/Plugins+SDK#section-Plugins+SDK-Preparation)